# What are the references of the company names in "Orconomics"?

Tags: the-dark-profit-saga

I just finished reading *[Orconomics](https://www.jzacharypike.com/books/Orconomics/)*, first book of *The Dark Profit Saga*. It's a satire on corporate economics with adventurers and their loot acting as a sort of investment fund where kingdoms and other investors pay into the supply of heroes with an expected return on the items brought back, and a parallel to the [subprime mortgage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subprime_mortgage_crisis) involving loot amounts decreasing due to depleted resources (a combination of overfarming of hoards and a growing number of "monster races" getting their papers and joining the workforce) and overvaluation of the hoards by firms trying to keep their stock prices up.

A few of the names of the corporations seem to be puns on companies in our names, such as Goldson Baggs (Goldman Sachs) and Lamia Sisters (Lehman Brothers), but I'm sure I'm missing other references. What are they?

Comment: It occurs to me that part of the problem may be that you're hoping someone else will dig out a copy of *Orconomics* and spend a few hours looking through each page of it, hunting for funny corporate names which might be the ones you're thinking of, and then commenting on what they remind him of. I'm not surprised that you haven't had any takers yet. Might do better to ask directly about *specific* corporate names which are mentioned, and see if anyone says, "Sure, that rings a bell! It sounds like a distorted version of [insert real-world name]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial list on [the TVTropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheDarkProfitSaga):

- Goldson Baggs Group, Inc (Goldman Sachs Group, Inc.)
- Lamia Sisters (Lehman Brothers)
- Citistate (Citibank)
- J.P. Gorgon (J.P. Morgan)